# Models are not linking

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, scaffolding

I'm a newbie to scaffolding.  I'm using VS 2019 and I'm trying to scaffold a few models.  Only thing is when I run the scaffolding process it only generates the code for the album model.
This what I'm doing for the scaffolding process
[image]

Album Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication36.Models
{
    public class Album
    {
        public virtual int AlbumId { get; set; }
        public virtual int GenreId { get; set; }
        public virtual int ArtistId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual decimal Price { get; set;}
        public virtual string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
        public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Artist model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication36.Models
{
    public class Artist
    {
        public virtual int ArtistId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Genera Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication36.Models
{
    public class Genre
    {
        public virtual int GenreId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Data context Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WebApplication36.Models
{
    public class WebApplication36Context : DbContext
    {
        public WebApplication36Context (DbContextOptions<WebApplication36Context> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<WebApplication36.Models.Album> Album { get; set; }


    }
}
```

As can be seen there is a reference to both the artist model and the genera model in the album model, but when I scaffold the album model the other two are not being pulled into the data context class.  Why?  What am I doing wrong?  I am working out of an older MVC5 book and this is VS2019, is this normal in 2019?

Comment: Why are all of your properties marked virtual?

Answer (score 0):

Model classes with or without any reference to other model classes are need to be added in Dbcontext class. You need to add them manually.

```
    public DbSet<WebApplication36.Models.Album> Album { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WebApplication36.Models.Artist> Artist { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WebApplication36.Models.Genre> Genre { get; set; }
```